# Intel Power Gadget causes kernel panics

Tags: crash, catalina, kernel-panic, macos

The latest version of Intel Power Gadget (3.6.1) is causing frequent kernel panics in macOS Catalina (10.15.1), causing the system to freeze and then shut down. This happens when some app is already running and I use spotlight to launch the Intel Power Gadget.

How can I fix this?

Here's the panic string for the incident:

```
macOSPanicString : panic(cpu 6 caller 0xffffff801a262e0a): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f9e4f6339, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x00000000000d447c, CR3: 0x00000004435c514a, CR4: 0x00000000003626e0
RAX: 0x0000000000014068, RBX: 0x0000000000000007, RCX: 0x0000000000030105, RDX: 0x0000000000010057
RSP: 0xffffff8209d98f30, RBP: 0xffffff8209d98f60, RSI: 0x0000000000010058, RDI: 0xffffff8059b959c0
R8:  0x0000000000000003, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0x0000000000000000, R11: 0x0000000000000000
R12: 0x000000000007a74f, R13: 0x0000000000001004, R14: 0x0000000000000000, R15: 0xffffff806137f1a0
RFL: 0x0000000000010083, RIP: 0xffffff7f9e4f6339, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Fault CR2: 0x00000000000d447c, Error code: 0x0000000000000002, Fault CPU: 0x6, PL: 1, VF: 5

Backtrace (CPU 6), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8209d98990 : 0xffffff801a139a3b 
0xffffff8209d989e0 : 0xffffff801a270fe5 
0xffffff8209d98a20 : 0xffffff801a262a5e 
0xffffff8209d98a70 : 0xffffff801a0e0a40 
0xffffff8209d98a90 : 0xffffff801a139127 
0xffffff8209d98b90 : 0xffffff801a13950b 
0xffffff8209d98be0 : 0xffffff801a8d17f9 
0xffffff8209d98c50 : 0xffffff801a262e0a 
0xffffff8209d98dd0 : 0xffffff801a262b08 
0xffffff8209d98e20 : 0xffffff801a0e0a40 
0xffffff8209d98e40 : 0xffffff7f9e4f6339 
0xffffff8209d98f60 : 0xffffff801a26acd1 
0xffffff8209d98f80 : 0xffffff801a26225b 
0xffffff8209d98fd0 : 0xffffff801a0e0bed 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.intel.driver.EnergyDriver(3.6.1)[CF3549FA-B79E-34E2-BF25-6C5FEF5EF262]@0xffffff7f9e4f5000->0xffffff7f9e4f8fff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: BL2
Boot args: chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev

Mac OS version:
19B88

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.0.0: Thu Oct 17 16:17:15 PDT 2019; root:xnu-6153.41.3~29/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 7503CD47-851F-321E-8747-50DB4299165F
Kernel slide:     0x0000000019e00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff801a000000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8019f00000
System model name: MacBookPro15,1 (Mac-937A206F2EE63C01)
System shutdown begun: NO

System uptime in nanoseconds: 170839497305610
last loaded kext at 168765961853818: >usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice    1.2 (addr 0xffffff7f9e473000, size 45056)
last unloaded kext at 169075379128440: >!UAudio 320.49 (addr 0xffffff7f9f892000, size 434176)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  6.0.12
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  6.0.12
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 6.0.12
org.pqrs.driver.Karabiner.VirtualHIDDevice.v061000  6.10.0
com.intel.driver.EnergyDriver   3.6.1
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 6.0.12
@filesystems.smbfs  3.4
@kext.AMDFramebuffer    3.0.2
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000    3.0.2
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   3.0.2
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 4.5.9
@fileutil   20.036.15
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   4.5.9
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.1f1
>pmtelemetry    1
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>AGPM   111.2.5
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!A!IKBLGraphics    14.0.2
>AGDCBacklightControl   4.5.9
>BridgeAudioCommunication   6.55
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.3
@kext.AMD9500!C 3.0.2
>!AMuxControl2  4.5.9
>!AAVEBridge    6.1
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3410.1
>!AHIDALSService    1
>!ABridgeAudio!C    6.55
>!AGFXHDA   100.1.422
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.2
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!AMCCSControl  1.13
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.0.9
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
>!AVirtIO   1.0
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe  1
@filesystems.apfs   1412.41.1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>usb.!UHub  1.2
@kext.AMDRadeonX4100HWLibs  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000HWServices  3.0.2
|IOUSBUserClient    900.4.2
|IOAVB!F    800.17
>!ASSE  1.0
@!AGPUWrangler  4.5.9
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    7.0.1f1
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.1f1
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>!AGraphicsControl  4.5.9
>!AActuatorDriver   3410.2
>!AHS!BDriver   3410.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.1f1
>!AMultitouchDriver 3410.2
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3410.1
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IONDRVSupport  568
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
@kext.AMDSupport    3.0.2
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    4.5.9
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.2.7
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
|IOGraphics!F   568
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    810.1
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
@kext.triggers  1.0
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
|IOSurface  269.6
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!ABCMWLANCore  1.0.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IO80211!FV2    1200.12.2b1
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.2
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.3
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.3
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.0
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.4.6
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.41.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.0.2
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
|IOTimeSync!F   810.1
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 7.0.1f1
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.1f1
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.40.7
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.0.2
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.Libm   1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
```

Answer (score 9):

Update: Intel Power Gadget for Mac v3.6.2 should resolve this issue: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-power-gadget

I'm the owner of Intel Power Gadget for Mac. Please contact me at powergadget@intel.com so I can work with you to debug this issue.

Comment: Wow - that’s super service. If you can share a little on the fix / diagnosis later, even better.

Comment: While it's great that you'll work on the issue, this should've been a comment and not an answer.  You can improve it by editing the details and root cause of the problem into the answer.  This will also help others who have a similar problem.

Comment: @fsb Agreed, but I didn't have enough reputation to post a comment at that time.

Comment: 3.6.2 download link is broken on that page

Answer (score 1):

Other than checking for Catalina-specific updates for Intel Power Gadget, or logging a bug with Intel, you could try disabling other kernel extensions one by one to see if it's related to an interaction to any of those. For example, from your kernel panic I see you could potentially disable:

- Karabiner
- VirtualBox
- Network sharing ("filesystems.smbfs")

Answer (score 0):

I have a 2019 macbook pro 15" running 10.15.2 and when I tried to open the intel power gadget, it crashed the entire computer and restarted. I got a message after the reboot saying the computer restarted because of a problem.

The crash log points to the kernel extension by intel. I also ran the command line to see the cause of the previous shutdown and it gave a code of -20. I couldn't find any info regarding -20 crash code on macOS. I uninstalled the power gadget. Will see if this solves the problem.